# Catch Guzzle Exception and return string

Tags: php, guzzle

So I need some help on building out one of my methods for retrieving twitter lists using IDs. Below, I will describe and go into detail on what it's returning.

**Code**:

```
    public static function get_list($list_id)
    {
        $lists = self::get_lists();
        $params = [
            'list.fields' => 'created_at,follower_count,member_count,private,description,owner_id',
            'user.fields' => 'created_at,description,entities,id,location,name,pinned_tweet_id,profile_image_url,protected,public_metrics,url,username,verified,withheld'
        ];
        try {
            $list = $lists->get($list_id, $params);
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
            return $e;
        }

        return $list;
    }
```

---

When `$lists->get()` has an issue, it throws the following items `object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)#1640 (10) { ["request":"GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException":private]=>` error.

**What I'd like to achieve**:
Return `$e` so that I can read the error (**Unable to get this to work**).

If I switch out `return $e` for `return 'Hello'`, I still see the object and not the string.

The IDE suggests that it `@throws GuzzleException`.

Does anyone see anything wrong in how I'm handling my exception and why I'm unable to properly return the exception error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use exception hierarchy to catch any exception. `ClientException` only catches status code between 400x-499. To catch other exception or catch within the same Exception you can use `RequestException`.

```
public static function get_list($list_id)
    {
        $lists = self::get_lists();
        $params = [
            'list.fields' => 'created_at,follower_count,member_count,private,description,owner_id',
            'user.fields' => 'created_at,description,entities,id,location,name,pinned_tweet_id,profile_image_url,protected,public_metrics,url,username,verified,withheld'
        ];
        try {
            $list = $lists->get($list_id, $params);
            if($list->getStatusCode() == 200)){
                $return_list = json_decode($list->getBody(),true);
            }
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
            $error['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            $error['request'] = $e->getRequest();
            if($e->hasResponse()){
              // you can pass a specific status code to catch a particular error here I have catched 400 Bad Request. 
              if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400'){
                 $error['response'] = $e->getResponse(); 
              }
            }
            return $error;
        } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $se){
            $error['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            $error['request'] = $e->getRequest();
            return $error;
        } catch(Exception $e){
           //other errors 
        }

        return $list;
    }
```